# jQuery scrollTop not working locally

Tags: jquery

I've boiled the code down to these lines:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script>

$(function(){
 var stop = $("#gettingstarted").offset().top;
 var delay = 1000;
 $('html').animate({scrollTop: stop}, delay);
});
</script>
...
<h3 id="gettingstarted">Getting Started</h3>
```

Yet it doesn't work locally. You can check out the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ez9Q/ which does work.

Firefox 26.0. Also, I know that it should be $('html,body') to work in all browsers, but I'm just trying to get it to work in Firefox. jQuery is working: I can do other stuff with the jQuery library.

**Edit:** Well, I added jQuery mobile (1.3.0-beta) and it made it work. No where did I read I had to have that. Strange.

Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Is it the only thing on the page when you run it locally - this script and `<h3>` element? What about images, are there any?

Comment: What exactly is happening? Is it not animating it, or is it just not moving at all?

Comment: You didn't check the console for 404 errors?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "locally"?

Comment: No images; my CSS doesn't affect anything. There's other mark-up, but that shouldn't affect this.

And the problem is that it's not animating. It's doing nothing.

"Locally" means "on my local server." Other servers are a-ok.

Answer (score 3):

Add the https to this line

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
```

When you run locally from `file://C:/some/file.html` not `http://localhost/some/site` it tries to load `file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js`. Common mistake.

You could save the jquery file locally and set the correct relative path, but then you'd have to change it for deployment unless you serve the jquery file too, but it's a good idea to call external resources from their own CDN, which you're doing already.

It's best that you use `http://` locally rather than `file://` anyway.